# Graphite & statsd generating many nodes

Tags: python, node.js, graphite, statsd, graphite-carbon

I just installed Graphite & statsd to get some statistics for my web-application. It already tracks the data, but it generates way too many nodes inside the Graphite webapp's tree. See attached image:
[a busy cat http://mmeg-de.gefaellt-mir.me/media/hm.PNG](http://mmeg-de.gefaellt-mir.me/media/hm.PNG)

I already googled but I couldn't find any explanation for this. I only want to track how many times my index page was accessed. I do this in Python with the following command:

```
statsd.incr('mmeg.de.aufrufe.index')
```

Does anybody have an explanation for this? Why are there so many (different) graphs? I thought there would be just one graph showing me how many times my index page was accessed over time.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your user's profile and turn off the Advanced UI. The wildcard folders are a feature of the Advanced UI.